# Django admin - add custom app which displays existing 'User' data?

Tags: python, django, django-admin, models

[image: Here's the screenshot:]

I need the Pending Users(in the picture above) to display the same data in users, ie. **when a user is added, it should also be added in pending user.**

This is my **models.py:**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class PendingUser(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

I tried adding this in **admin.py** of *pending app:* But it doesn't work

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.admin.sites import AdminSite, site
from pending.models import PendingUser
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class PendingUserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', )
    def username(self, request):
            return User.objects.get('username')

    def email(self, request):
            return User.objects.get('email')

    def first_name(self, request):
            return User.objects.get('first_name')

    def last_name(self, request):
            return User.objects.get('last_name')

admin.site.register(PendingUser, PendingUserAdmin)
```

When I try to makemigrations, this error occurs: `You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'user' to pendinguser without a default; we can't do that (the database needs
 something to populate existing rows).`
What is wrong? Is there another way to do this?

Comment: 1. I would say that error is very clear: you need some kind of default to put in the user column for existing rows. If you don't care about the data of course, you can just delete the whole lot before migrating. 2. All of those methods in the admin class are **complete nonsense**, and you should remove them completely.

Answer (score 0):

There's many error. The PendingUser and User is not related each other.

1. Model `PendingUser` has no relation with User (django.contrib.auth.models.Users).
2. User.objects.get(user__id =request.id).username. You will not get id in request (`request.id`). This portion `user__id` is not correct way to do just inches you are filtering user based on id. The right way is `User.objects.get(id=some_id)`

Comment: Okay thanks, how to create the relation? And can you suggest any way to do this?

Comment: You have to use django Foreign key https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey

Comment: hi, I've made your suggested changes, but it gives the error: `pending.PendingUser.user: (fields.E300) Field defines a relation with model 'User', which is either not installed, or is abstract.`

Comment: Remove the ' sign from 'User' in line user = models.ForeignKey('User')